# compose string if argument is not nil and return nil if argument is nil

Tags: ruby

Is there a more elegant way do do this?

```
def my_method1(options={})
  (options[:age]) ? "my string #{options[:age]}" : nil
end

def my_method2(options={})
  (options[:age]) ? "my string #{options[:age]}" : ""
end
```

Comment: Will `options[:age]` ever be `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def my_method1(options={})
  "my string #{options[:age]}" if options[:age]
end

def my_method2(options={})
  my_method1(options).to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_method1(options={})
  oa = options[:age]
  oa.nil? ? nil : "my string #{oa}"
end

def my_method2(options={})
  oa = options[:age]
  oa.nil? ? '' : "my string #{oa}"
end
```